# Context menu for Tabulator

Tags: tabulator

I try to use column header menus and row context menus in my tabulator but nothing appear. Then I realize in the DOM that the menu is there but out of the window and at the top of the tree in the dom, it's the div with the class tabulator-menu.

[The DOM, the div with smd take the whole page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYGDc.png)

I use Vuejs with Bootstrap 4.

How to make it appear at the right place ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The menu is appearing in exactly the correctly place in the DOM.

It is standard practice in a lot of context menu libraries to append the menu directly to the `body` rather than to the element that triggered it, this happens because menus are often long and overflow their containing element, by absolutely positioning the elements in the DOM the sit on top of these and prevent this being an issue.

It is hard to  say without seeing an example, but it is likely a z-index issue that is causing the problem.

By default Tabulator menus have a z-index of 10,000 if you have anything with a z-index higher than this it will sit over the menu.

To resolve this you simply need to add a bit of CSS after you have imported the tablator style sheet, that changes the `z-index` to be higher than any others on your page:

```css
.tabulator-menu{
    z-index: 99999999;
}
```